エラーを直す為には、LightGBMのバージョンを確認したりtrain()メソッドの引数を確認する必要があるのでしょうか
Jupyter Notebookを使って、以下の記事の内容を練習していますが、エラーが出てしまいました。
【図解で解説】LightGBMの仕組みとPythonでの実装を見ていこう！
エラー
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 111
    105 params = {
    106     "objective": "regression",
    107     "metric": "mae"
    108 }
    110 # early_stopping_rounds を元に戻して試す
--> 111 model = lgb.train(
    112     params, 
    113     trains, 
    114     valid_sets=[valids],  # valid_setsをリストに
    115     valid_names=["validation"],  # valid_namesを追加
    116     num_boost_round=1000, 
    117     early_stopping_rounds=100  # 再度early_stopping_roundsに戻す
    118 )
    122 # モデルのトレーニング (valid_namesを追加)
    123 model = lgb.train(
    124     params, 
    125     trains, 
   (...)
    129     early_stopping_rounds=100
    130 )

TypeError: train() got an unexpected keyword argument 'early_stopping_rounds'

コード
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error as mae
import re

# ファイルの読み込み
files = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Nishika\train\*.csv")
data_list = []
for file in files:
    data_list.append(pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0))
df = pd.concat(data_list)

# データ前処理関数の修正版
def data_pre(df):
    nonnull_list = []
    for col in df.columns:
        nonnull = df[col].count()
        if nonnull == 0:
            nonnull_list.append(col)
    df = df.drop(nonnull_list, axis=1)

    df = df.drop("市区町村名", axis=1)
    df = df.drop("種類", axis=1)


# 最寄駅の距離を正規表現を使って変換
def convert_distance(x):
    if pd.isna(x):
        return np.nan
    x = re.sub(r'[分]', '', x)
    if 'H' in x:
        x = float(x.replace('H', '')) * 60  # 'H'を時間として処理
    elif '～' in x:
        x = x.split('～')[0]  # 範囲の場合は最小の値を使用
    return float(x)


    df["最寄駅：距離（分）"] = df["最寄駅：距離（分）"].apply(convert_distance)

    df["面積（㎡）"] = df["面積（㎡）"].replace("2000㎡以上", 2000).astype(float)

    y_list = {}
    for i in df["建築年"].value_counts().keys():
        if "平成" in i:
            num = float(i.split("平成")[1].split("年")[0])
            year = 33 - num
        if "令和" in i:
            num = float(i.split("令和")[1].split("年")[0])
            year = 3 - num
        if "昭和" in i:
            num = float(i.split("昭和")[1].split("年")[0])
            year = 96 - num
        y_list[i] = year
    y_list["戦前"] = 76
    df["建築年"] = df["建築年"].replace(y_list)

    # 取引時点の変換
    year = {
        "年第１四半期": ".25",
        "年第２四半期": ".50",
        "年第３四半期": ".75",
        "年第４四半期": ".99"
    }
    year_list = {}
    for i in df["取引時点"].value_counts().keys():
        year_rep = i
        for k, j in year.items():
            if k in i:
                year_rep = i.replace(k, j)
        year_list[i] = year_rep
    df["取引時点"] = df["取引時点"].replace(year_list).astype(float)

    for col in ["都道府県名", "地区名", "最寄駅：名称", "間取り", "建物の構造", "用途", "今後の利用目的", "都市計画", "改装", "取引の事情等"]:
        df[col] = df[col].astype("category")

    return df

# データ前処理の実行
def data_pre(df):
    # 前処理のコード...
    
    return df  # 最後にデータフレームを返す
print(df.head())  # データの最初の数行を確認


# 学習用・検証用データの分割
df_train, df_val = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2)

# モデルのトレーニング
col = "取引価格（総額）_log"
train_y = df_train[col]
train_x = df_train.drop(col, axis=1)

val_y = df_val[col]
val_x = df_val.drop(col, axis=1)

# LightGBM Datasetを作成
trains = lgb.Dataset(train_x, label=train_y)
valids = lgb.Dataset(val_x, label=val_y, reference=trains)

# モデルのトレーニング
params = {
    "objective": "regression",
    "metric": "mae"
}

# early_stopping_rounds を元に戻して試す
model = lgb.train(
    params, 
    trains, 
    valid_sets=[valids],  # valid_setsをリストに
    valid_names=["validation"],  # valid_namesを追加
    num_boost_round=1000, 
    early_stopping_rounds=100  # 再度early_stopping_roundsに戻す
)



# モデルのトレーニング (valid_namesを追加)
model = lgb.train(
    params, 
    trains, 
    valid_sets=[valids],  # valid_setsをリストに
    valid_names=["validation"],  # valid_namesを追加
    num_boost_round=1000, 
    early_stopping_rounds=100
)


# テストデータの予測
df_test = pd.read_csv("test.csv", index_col=0)
df_test = data_pre(df_test)

predict = model.predict(df_test)
df_test["取引価格（総額）_log"] = predict
df_test[["取引価格（総額）_log"]].to_csv("submit_test.csv")


そのエラーメッセージで検索するとこんな記事が見つかるので参考にしてみてはどうでしょう？ LightGBMのearly_stoppingの仕様が変わったので、使用法を調べてみた, LightGBMのtrain関数の引数からコールバックへの移行, early_stopping_rounds in lightgbm

ありがとうございます！　見てみます
